# SharePoint Profile Synchronization - don't import users from trusted domain

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, userprofiles

We have a two way trust configured between our 2 domains. I am trying to set up SharePoint Profile Synchronization, but I do not wish to import the users from the trusted domain. Is there a way to tell SharePoint to not import those users?

Using Active Directory Import sync type isn't an option unfortunately since we need to use Exchange Task sync and that requires the User Profile Sync service to be running. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Configure Synchronization Connections only for those domains from where you want users in central admin under user profile sync service.